# How to embed ruby/erb code into an inline html style tag?(progress bar)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am trying to do a progress bar on a rails index page. I loop through assignments on each page and then show their completion percentage.

However I have the following bootstrap code in here to show the progress bar:

```
<% class:"progress-bar", role:"progressbar", aria-valuenow:"60", aria-valuemin:"0", aria-valuemax:"100", style:"width: 60%;" %>
```

I need to somehow be able to change the style:"width: 60%;" to be able to read something like `<%= width: assignment.completion %>` so that it each assignment has the completion saved in the database for that assignment.

How is something like this achieved?

Comment: This does not really make any sense, since the code you supplied does not actually do anything. Do you think you could rephrase or even better add an example of the desired HTML output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this style:** 
`width: <%= assignment.completion %>`